# Returning cstring from function

Tags: c++, validation, c-strings

Need to use cstrings for an assignment, so bear with me as I'm new to the concept.

The purpose of the assignment is to enter a password into a function, validate it against some criteria, then reverse the password and validate it again. There are three functions in total: one to get the password from the user, one for validation, and one to reverse what was entered.

Note: during the validation, each criteria not met has to be addressed in the invalid message returned to main.

Main:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char* Get_Pass(char p_word[]);
char* Valid_Pass(char p_word[]);
//char* Reverse_Pass(char p_word[]);

int main()
{
  const int SIZE = 31;
  char password[SIZE];

  char* rtn_stg = new char[SIZE];
  char* rtn_ptr;

  rtn_stg = Get_Pass(password);
  rtn_ptr = rtn_stg;
  cout << Valid_Pass(rtn_stg);

  //cout << Reverse_Pass(rtn_string, SIZE);

  delete[] rtn_ptr;

  cout << "\n\n";
  system("pause");
  return 0;
  }
```

The issue I'm experiencing is twofold; the first function works fine. If I disabled everything else and sent the result back to main, it would print what I entered. It's when passing the password into the second function for validation where it outputs garbage code, along with the message for the unmet criteria, for example:

"Enter password for verification: hello
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
═══════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²▌▌▌▌▌·ò=uYPassword must be si
x characters long. Password must contain one digit."

Here's the function in question:

```
char* Valid_Pass(char p_word[])
{
  int char_count = 0, digi_count = 0, up_count = 0, low_count = 0, index = 0;
  char mess_1[] = "Password must be six characters long. ";
  char mess_2[] = "Password must contain one digit. ";
  char mess_3[] = "Password must contain one upper and lower case letter. ";
  char mess_4[] = "Password valid.";

  const int SIZE = strlen(mess_1) + strlen(mess_2) + strlen(mess_3) + 1;
  char* out_message = new char[SIZE];

  while (p_word[index] != '\0')
  {
    if (isalpha(p_word[index]))
        char_count++;
    if (isdigit(p_word[index]))
        digi_count++;
    if (isupper(p_word[index]))
        up_count++;
    if (islower(p_word[index]))
        low_count++;
    index++;
  }
  if (index < 6)
    strcat(out_message, mess_1);
  if (digi_count < 1)
    strcat(out_message, mess_2);
  if (up_count < 1 && low_count < 1)
    strcat(out_message, mess_3);
  //if(index )
    //out_message = mess_4;

  return out_message;
}
```

On top of that, upon execution, it triggers a break point at the "delete[] rtn_ptr".

Any insight into this would be appreciated. Like I said above, I'm new to cstrings and couldn't find an solution on here that addressed the problems I'm experiencing.

Thanks!

Comment: use C++ instead of C with classes.

Comment: Why not simply using `std::string` and leave all the mess behind you?

Comment: As for working with c-style strings, ensure that you put a terminating `'\0'` character in the end.

Comment: Manual memory management - eeeew. At *least* learn about smart pointers.. better yet; use `std::string` already..  also learn about `std::array` and use it in place of  those pesky C arrays... would not pass code review in current form.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by use of `strcat` with `message_out` as argument.

The arguments to `strcat` need to be null-terminated strings. In your case, you have allocated memory for `message_out` but you have not initialized it anything before the first call to `strcat`. As a consequence, your program has undefined behavior.

Make sure you initialize it to an empty string before using `strcat`.

```
out_message[0] = '\0';
if (index < 6)
  strcat(out_message, mess_1);
if (digi_count < 1)
  strcat(out_message, mess_2);
if (up_count < 1 && low_count < 1)
  strcat(out_message, mess_3);
```